# using python `del` on a list index deletes the corresponding item in other identical lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, del

I'm new to using python's `del` keyword, and I ran into a problem.

I define two lists that have the same elements like this:

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> list2 = list1
```

I want to delete an element at a specific index in *only one of the lists.* However, when using python's `del` keyword, it deletes the same element in the other list. For example,

```
>>> del list1[3]
>>> list2
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
```

Because list1 is going to be a dynamic input, I have to define list2 to be equal to list1 instead of writing out the list. I also want to be able to delete at an index, and using python's `del` keyword is the only way I found to do that.

Is there any other method I can use to delete elements by index? Thanks!